# The 'formal' way to prove equivalence?

Tags: proof-writing

In school we were always taught to prove equivalence by splitting an equation into $LHS$ and $RHS$ and working with each side individually until $LHS = RHS$.

For example, prove:

$$2^{k + 1} - 2 = 2(2^k - 1)$$

Which could be done as follows:

$$RHS = 2(2^k - 1)$$

$$    = 2^1 \cdot 2^k - 2$$

$$    = 2^{k + 1} - 2$$

$$    = LHS$$

However, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation) (although it does not cite any sources):

> This abbreviation is seldom if ever used in print; it is very informal.

Is Wikipedia correct, and if this *is* "very informal", what is the proper, 'formal' way to prove equivalence (without the $LHS$ and $RHS$ abbreviations)?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen that in print...

Comment: I would at least agree that it is seldom used. Usually you just write the actual expression for the left/right hand side. So in this example, replace LHS by $2^{k+1}-2$ and RHS by $2(2^k-1)$. It makes it clearer anyway, because you don't have to look back to see what the left and right hand sides actually were.

Comment: As a referee, I would flag any uses of "LHS" or "RHS" in a paper as needing to be corrected before the paper is accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This concerns the abbreviations "LHS" and "RHS", and indeed these are a bit informal, in a formal text they would be probably written out fully as "*the left hand side of the above equation*...". It is also possible that these are just skipped, as

> **Prop.** $2^{k + 1} - 2 = 2(2^k - 1)$
>
> **Proof**: $2^{k+1} - 2 = 2^1\cdot 2^k -2=2\cdot (2^k-1)$.  -QED-